Does Stripe automatically add Idempotency to its payments
I have an app that creates double payments, and as a solution, I implemented idempotency by sending a unique ID in my request header from the app. However, I was wondering, if I don't include the key in my header or if the API doesn't have idempotency implemented, does Stripe automatically add an idempotency key to its payments to prevent double booking?
I ask because, from the logs in the Stripe dashboard, I can see an idempotency key present (though it's not the one I'm sending).

This sounds like a question for Stripe developer support, or maybe their documentation.

Stripe SDKs will automatically set an idempotency key when you make an API request. But this won't prevent double booking if your code is run twice, since each API request will have its own unique idempotency key.
You can override the default idempotency key by setting one yourself, as shown here.
